# Pаполнение переменной типа char числом превышающим 127

Tags: java, char

Задача посылать с java на контроллер коды длиной 5 байт в строковом типе. В java коды хранятся в виде String s="123456789A".... 
Делаем преобразование, что бы получить стоку состоящую из символов ASCII коды которых составляют изначальный код.
те. s="..." ASCII код этой s - 12 34 56 78 9A
И такую строку посылаем на контроллер.

Скрипт уже написан. В его основе преобразования string - int - char -string

Но для char в которые помещаем число больше чем 127 перобразования получаются странные.

```
private String convert2(String source){
    char c1='\u007F';
    return Character.toString(c1);
}
```

После такого скрипта на контроллер приходит символ с ASCII  кодом 7F

```
private String convert2(String source){
    char c2='\u0080';
    return Character.toString(c1);
}
```

А после такого скрипта на контроллер приходит символ с ASCII  кодом С2 80

Почему так происходит?

Comment: каким образом вы посылаете строки в контроллер? речь ведь о микроконтроллере?

Comment: Да, микроконтроллер. Посылаем по сокету. Этот механизм отлажен. Контроллер Tibbo. Подключается к интеграционной платформе, AggreGate. Эта платформа и использует скрипт. Сам механизм отлажен, проблема именно в скрипте.

Comment: java это не скриптовый язык. так что это не скрипт. важно понимать какая кодировка установлена на сокете.

Comment: Сейчас проверил как отрабатывает программа вообще без связи с контроллером. т.е.    String convert2(String source){
    char c2='\u0080';
    return Character.toString(c1);
} возвращает символ ¡ и этот символ имеет ASCII код C2A1.

Comment: вы проверили код из ответа?

Comment: Да. Но пока еще не все понятно